# Running keytool, getting an error with the -file param?

Tags: bash, shell, keytool

I'm reading this article about how to allow a self-signed cert to be used by an android client:

http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html#comment-form

On step 2, I have to run a few commands, but I'm not too familiar with the shell and am getting a syntax error when trying to run the following:

```
export CLASSPATH="/Users/me/Desktop/lib/java/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16-145.jar"
CERTSTORE=res/raw/mystore.bks
if [ -a $CERTSTORE ]; then
    rm $CERTSTORE || exit 1
fi
keytool \
  -import \
  -v \
  -trustcacerts \
  -alias 0 \
  -file <(openssl x509 -in mycert.pem) \
  -keystore $CERTSTORE \
  -storetype BKS \
  -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider \
  -providerpath /usr/share/java/bcprov.jar \
  -storepass mypassword
```

The error I get when I run:

```
./test.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.sh: line 11: `  -file <(openssl x509 -in mycert.pem) \'
```

So the -file syntax is problematic, but I'm not sure what to change this to, because I don't know what syntax the -file param can handle.

Anyone have any idea? I'm on mac 10.6,

Thanks

--------- Update ---------------

If I replace the "<" character with "$", I get the following exception when executed:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, CERTIFICATE----- is not a legal command
  at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.parseArgs(KeyTool.java:375)
  at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:171)
  at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:166)
```

hmm I'm not understanding which arg the exception is telling me is bad though. Script updated looks like:

```
export CLASSPATH="/Users/me/Desktop/lib/java/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16-145.jar"
CERTSTORE=res/raw/mystore.bks
if [ -a $CERTSTORE ]; then
  rm $CERTSTORE || exit 1
fi
keytool \
  -import \
  -v \
  -trustcacerts \
  -alias 0 \
  -file $(openssl x509 -in mycert.pem) \
  -keystore $CERTSTORE \
  -storetype BKS \
  -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider \
  -providerpath /usr/share/java/bcprov.jar \
  -storepass mypassword
```

Thanks!

Comment: A dollar sign isn't going to work. That puts the output of the `openssl` command on the command line so it's trying to execute the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not be running Bash. The `<()` is called process substitution. Some other shells support it, but the Bourne shell does not.

It creates an anonymous named pipe, so the `-file` sees a filename, but the file contents are really the output of `openssl x509` command.

You can probably solve the problem by making sure that the first line in the script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: Ah hmm - I am just running this through console on my mac. I added the #!/bin/bash statement at the top of the script, but same error when trying to run it (sh ./test.sh)

Comment: @user291701: No, if you run it like that, the Bourne shell is running it. Either run it like this: `bash ./test.sh` or make it executable (`chmod +x test.sh`) and run it like this: `./test.sh`.

Comment: Ah awesome running it like "bash ./test.sh" got it to execute properly (I get a class not found exception related to the bouncy castle jar, but that's probably cause i didn't set it in the classpath properly). Thanks!

Comment: @user291701: I'm glad you've made progress. Thanks for accepting my answer. Don't forget, you can also upvote answers that you accept plus any other answers or questions (anywhere on the sites that you have voting [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges)) that you find good for any reason (downvoting can be done, too).